# Can I run code-contracts analysis manually?

Tags: c#, timeout, code-contracts

When I rebuild my C# app I often don't get the results of my code-contracts analysis.  This is caused by the following error message

`CodeContracts: MyApp.Client.Model: Analysis method MyApp.Client.Model.MyClass.CreateCalculatedElements(System.Collections.Generic.List1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2<System.String,MyCompany.Scripting.ICompiledFunction1<System.Object>>>,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<System.String,MyCompany.Scripting.ICompiledFunction1<System.Decimal>>,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2<System.String,MyCompany.Scripting.ICompiledFunction1<System.Decimal>>) timed out`

Here is the definition of the method

```
internal void CreateCalculatedElements(
List<KeyValuePair<string, ICompiledFunction<object>>> preFinalCalculationScripts,
Dictionary<string, ICompiledFunction<decimal>> factorCalculators,
Dictionary<string, ICompiledFunction<decimal>> elementCalculators)
```

This doesn't always time out. Is there a way I can manually run contract checking just for one project rather than all of them via a rebuild-solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the timeout for that project by adding an extra option to the static checking options in the property pane as follows: -timeout

The default is 180, which is per method.

As to your original question, yes you can run the tools manually as follows:

Say your project P is in directory D, then go to D\obj\Debug\Decl. In there you'll find a convenient file called Pcccheck.rsp which contains the parameters which were passed to cccheck during the build. To run the analysis again, you simply issue:
cccheck @Pcccheck.rsp

Right now, there isn't an option to trigger a re-analysis of just one project without a rebuild.

Comment: dir *.rsp /s reveals no .rsp files anywhere within my project folder or child folders.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. You aren't using some really old version are you? We introduced .rsp files a long time ago. These files only get written when you actually enable the static checker and did at least one build. They are also deleted when you clean the build.

Comment: Manuel, is there a feature planned to support manually running the static analysis on Visual Studio? It would be very useful to our team to be able to run it similarly to Code Analysis (FxCop), which has a dialog where you can select a project or the whole solution and run the analysis against that.